# Need help to do question E) only

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here][1]

the question picture here [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwtU.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we already know by a) and b) that $V=\ker P\oplus{\rm ran}\,P$ where $\ker P$ is the eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$ and ${\rm ran}\,P$, the range of $P$, is the eigenspace for eigenvalue $1$.

Additionally, d) implies that with the assumption $\forall v:\|P(v)\|\le\|v\|$ of e), we also have $\ker P\perp{\rm ran}\,P$.

Now, if $v=v_1+v_2,\ w=w_1+w_2$ with $v_1,w_1\in{\rm ran}\,P,\ v_2,w_2\in\ker P$ (specifically $v_1=P(v),\,w_1=P(w)$), then
$$\langle P(v),w\rangle=\langle v_1,w_1\rangle=\langle v,P(w)\rangle$$